# Next DateTime object pertaining to a time

Tags: python, datetime

I am looking to convert a set daily maintenance window + UTC offset to the next occurrence of this maintenance window.

Let's say a maintenance window is 10PM-4AM and the UTC offset is -4. What I would like to do is generate a datetime object for both the start and end of the next occurrence of that maintenance window.

As an example, if it is currently 6/2/2014 1:40PM with a UTC offset of -4, I would want 6/3/2014 02:00AM UTC and 6/3/2014 08:00AM UTC

Additionally, if it is currently within the maintenance window, I would want the current window start and end.

ie if it's currently 6/2/2014 10:30PM with a UTC offset of -4, I would still want 6/3/2014 02:00AM UTC and 6/3/2014 08:00AM UTC

Edit:
Also acceptable, and perhaps even preferred, would be the same method but with just the time instead of date. I need to be able to store it in a MySQL DB, so if there is a good way for me to do this without including date, I'm open to it!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a hard time trying to figure out how to pass offsets to pytz or datetime, so I opted to just write my own converter:

```
def convert_utc(hour, minute, offset):

    utchour = hour - math.floor(offset)
    utcminute = minute

    #Parts of India are offset by half an hour
    if offset%1 == 0.5:
        #minutes
        if offset > 0:
            utchour -= 1
        utcminute = minute + 30

    if utchour > 24:
        utchour -= 24
    if utchour < 0:
        utchour = 24 + utchour

    return int(utchour), int(utcminute)
```